# How to fix "Request header field x-xsrf-token is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response" in Laravel Passport?

Tags: angular, laravel-passport, pkce

I'm using Laravel Passport implementation for the Authorization Code grant with (PKCE) to authenticate my SPA (Angular) to access my Laravel API.
The Laravel backend's domain is "domain-a.com", the app is at "localhost:8100".
I run into the following error at the first step (when the Laravel backend redirects the consuming application to the "redirect uri" sent via POST to the /oauth/authorize route):

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8100/success?code=def5020...jyrgCka1m4ARVNeuMeFske5EJu75ZwIfeVvLrEb' (redirected from 'https://domain-b.com/login') from origin 'https://domain-b.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field x-xsrf-token is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Here is my config/cors.php file:

```
    'paths' => [
        'api/*',
        'oauth/*',
    ],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => false,
```

And this is my Passport client (DB values):

```
| id | user_id | name                          | secret                                   | provider | redirect                                               | personal_access_client | password_client | revoked | created_at          | updated_at          |
|  4 |    NULL | PKCE  v2 | NULL                                     | NULL     | http://localhost:8100/success |                      0 |               0 |       0 | 2023-07-31 14:47:56 | 2023-07-31 14:47:56 |
```

Can anybody explain what is going on? Thank you very much!

Comment: Looks very similar to this one [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41390548/x-xsrf-token-not-allowed-in-headers-laravel-5-3-angular2?rq=2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41390548/x-xsrf-token-not-allowed-in-headers-laravel-5-3-angular2?rq=2)

Comment: @FelipeCaparelli it does, indeed...but that is a really old post and its solution should be already included on new Laravel CORS Middleware.